# Dynamic ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I'm trying to hide div based on input. Its a list with a id so currently my div looks like:

```
<div class="animate-show" ng-hide="'hide'-{{item.Id}}">
```

this outputs: `'hide'-1` in the `ng-hide`. I've tried removing the '' but then it does not work.

The plan is that each item gets a button, when the button is clicked it would then apply `$scope.hide-1 = true;`, animating a fade out for that item.

Has anyone hidden items in a list (divs in div) based on button click? How do I go about it?

Comment: I'm guessing `item` is the one from `ng-repeat="item in items"` right? Then just do `ng-hide="item.hidden"` and `ng-click="item.hidden = true"`.

Comment: Can you post HTML template? There is unclear moments about how `$scope.hide-1` is constructed.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct dynamic scope property name like this:

```
<div class="animate-show" ng-hide="this['hide-' + item.Id]">
```

Inside of `ngHide` `this` points to the scope object (`$scope`), then you just use bracket notation to build property name using variable.

Note, that `$scope.hide-1` is invalid notation, so it would better be `$scope.hide1`.

Comment: How to you trigger that animation? $scope.hide-??item.Id?? = true?

Comment: To trigger Angular animation you need to set up corresponding CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function:

```
ng-hide="shouldHide(item.Id)"
```

And in the controller:

```
var itemIdsToHide = {};

$scope.shouldHide = function(itemId) {
    return itemIdsToHide[itemId];
};

$scope.hideItem = function(itemId) {
    itemIdsToHide[itemId] = true;
};

$scope.showItem = function(itemId) {
    delete itemIdsToHide[itemId];
};
```